# Generating a random integer within a range for each day

Tags: random

I am writing an application where I need a persistent random integer within a range for each day. The number should be different but persistent for each passing day. The output should be as uniform as possible, but distribution quality doesn't have to be the best. I'd prefer a simple and "good enough" solution to this problem.

What kind of algorithm can I use for this?

Input: Current day (for example, an integer denoting days since some epoch)
Output: A random integer between X and Y

Thank you.

Edit: The platform I'm working in does not have a seeded PRNG implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm:

1. Seed RNG with current day
2. Generate one random number
3. Mod *y*, add *x*

Replace step three with a smarter algorithm if you want uniform probabilities.

**EDIT**: ok, you don't have a PRNG. Then you might want to apply some hash algorithm to the current date and treat that as a random number.

Comment: Thanks, I should have added that the platform I'm working in does not have a native seeded PRNG as far as I know.

Comment: @rokit: then you might want to apply a hash algorithm to the current date and treat that as a random number.

Comment: @rokit: Could you add that piece of info `that the platform I'm working in does not have a native seeded PRNG` to the original question for the rest of the world to know? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to write the algorithm yourself or just need a programming solution.

For the latter, you could use something along these lines:

```
new Random((DateTime.Today - new DateTime(1970,1,1)).Days)
    .Next(min, max)
```

That's in C# but you get the idea:

- use a fixed beginning date
- count the days since then
- use that number of days as the `seed` for the random number generator
- get a number within your bound using a utility function e.g.